# combobox items not show in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a win form project in c#, there is a combo box in a datagridview.
it has 2 items which added in design. when I run the program, the combo box is empty.
why? please help me
I added the items in Design mode and it doesn't show anything then I added items programatically and it doesn't work either.

Here is the code:

```
  cbcCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvFolder.Rows[0].Cells[1];
  cbcCell.Items.Add("cat");
  cbcCell.Items.Add("dog");
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Any other code that fills the DGV?

Comment: It is filled in design mode

Comment: You really fill the DataGridView in designmode?

Answer (score -1):

Without too much information here, the likely problem here is that the `ComboBox` has the `ReadOnly` property set to `true`. You can fix this by going into `Design View`, click the little arrow that appears in the top left of the `DataGridView`, select `Edit Column`, select the appropiate column/cell, and change the `ReadOnly` property to `false`.